# i need to make dynamic array, but i have no idea how to do it. java

Tags: java, arrays

i have some method, making search in treetableview. My problem is about dynamic array:

```
public void someMethod(){
   SomeClass[] someClassArray = new Some Class[0];//initialization generated by ide
   for (int i=0; i<=dynamicInt; i++){
      someClassArray[i].setSomeInfo(someInfo);
   }
}
```

how can i init array, that will have no top border, in what i can use someClassArray[anyInt], because if i will init it like that:

```
SomeClass[] someClassArray = new SomeClass[topBorderInt];
```

i can't use something like that:

```
if(myInt>topBorderInt)someClassArray[myInt]=someClassItem;
```

Comment: now i can't use something like that:

                    searchPositions.get(j) = searchPositions.get(i);

Comment: Because `get` is only meant to read the elements. `ArrayList` also has a `set` method.

Comment: thanks, problem is solved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use `ArrayList` or (maybe) `HashMap`:

```
public void someMethod(int dynamicInt){

    ArrayList<SomeClass> someClassArray = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
       //SomeClass[] someClassArray = new Some Class[0];//initialization generated by ide
       for (int i=0; i<=dynamicInt; i++){
          SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
          c.setSomeInfo(getSomeInfo());
          someClassArray.add(c);
       }
    }
```

ArrayList is empty until you add something to it. It fills up when you add something. You can not set something at arbitrary index in ArrayList until it has been grown up to size>index by adding some data.

If you would like to store something at desired index, without the need of continuity of the array, then you should use:

```
 HashMap<Integer,SomeClass> someMap = new HashMap<Integer,SomeClass>();

 someMap.put(0, someClassObject1);
 someMap.put(10, someClassObject2);

 someMap.get(0); // will return someClassObject1
 someMap.get(3); // will return null
 someMap.get(10); // will return someClassObject2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use any implementaiton of List, for example: ArrayList, LinkedList... for the list in provided by java see

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called dynamic arrays in Java. When you define an array you should set the size. You can't change it on the run.

Either you have to manually create a new array and copy the existing elements to the new array with enough free space or you can use some Collection like ArrayList, Vector etc..